# Choose not to support iPhone 4 family

Tags: ios, app-store

Is there a direct plist entry to define that an app supports iPhone 5 and above?

Will an app get rejected for who's UI is best designed for iPhone 5 family and slightly poor designed for iPhone 4 family?

Comment: iOS app store review guideline 10.6- "Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are designing for iPhone. It should be both designed  for 3.5 inch and 4.0 inch displays otherwise you cannot submit for review. You should design your user interface to provide best user experience for your customers not to pass from Apple's review process. There is only 0.5 inch difference between those devices. So you do not need to alter all your user interface much. It can make very good design for small screen as well by minor changes. You are free to not design for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 Plus native screen size for now. Possible Apple will change it later on. There is no .plist entry for specially app supports for iPhone 5 and more. Now it is all managed from launch screen images.